# "this" is a global object after using call()

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have stored the names of the methods in a list.

```
var list = ['fn1', 'fn2', 'fn3', 'fn4'];
```

I select the method using some criteria dynamically. The methods are part of a larger class that are attached using `'prototype`

```
MyObj.prototype.selectfn = function(criteria) {
    var fn = list[sel];
    this[fn].call(this, arg1);
}
MyObj.prototype.fn1 = function(args) { // do something }
MyObj.prototype.fn2 = function(args) { // do something}
```

And so on. The problem is inside the selected "fn" function, the `this` variable appears as a global object even though I used `call()` I read the mozilla docs, but I'm not able to understand why this is so, can someone help out please?

It it helps, my environment is node.js 0.10.12.

Edit : It's a little hard to provide the correct sample code because my code involves callbacks in a lot of places, but I'll try to elucidate.

Assume two files `User.js` and `Helper.js`.

`User.js`

```
var m, h;
var Helper = require('./Helper');

function init() {
  // to simplify, assume the `this` here refers to `User`
  h = new Helper(this);
}

function doSomething() {
  // pass some criteria string
  h.selectfn(criteria);
}
```

`Helper.js`

```
var Helper = module.exports = function(user) {
  this.user = user;
}

Helper.prototype.selectfn = function(criteria) {
  // based on some criteria string, choose the function name from "list" array
  // here, the string "sel" holds the selected function name
  var fn = list[sel];
  this[fn].call(this.user, arg1); 
  // if I print to console, `this.user` is correct over here, but inside the function it shows as undefined
}

Helper.prototype.fn1 = function(args) {
  // Here, I talk to databases, so I have callbacks. Say, on a callback, the user property is to be updated. This is why I want to use `call()` so that the `this` refers to `User` and can be updated.
  // For example, if we want to update the "last-seen" date.
  this.lastseen = new Date();
}
```

Hope the little example made it clearer.

Comment: Can you please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that reproduces the problem?

Comment: How are you calling `selectfn()`? That's what will determine the value of `this`.

Comment: Why do you need to use `call` ? Why not `this[fn](arg1);`

Comment: What is `sel` and `arg1` and where are those values defined?

Comment: In reply to Jonathan, I'm instantiating MyObj in another file, and calling it.

Answer (score 0):

the first parameter of call() is your function context "this"

as example:

```
var someObject = {
  withAFunction: function(text) { alert('hello ' + text); }
};

var testFunction = function(text) {
   this.withAFunction(text);
};

testFunction.call(someObject, 'world');
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to review your code:

```
var list = ['fn1', 'fn2', 'fn3', 'fn4'];

//MyObj is copy of Object?
var MyObj = Object;
//or a preudoclass:
//var MyObj =  function(){};

//inside this function you use sel and arg1 that seems undefined and use like arguments criteria that seems useless

MyObj.prototype.selectfn = function(sel,arg1) {
    var fn = list[sel];
    this[fn].call(this, arg1); // this is MyObj istance.


MyObj.prototype.fn1 = function(args) { console.log("fn1", args);/* do something */ }
MyObj.prototype.fn2 = function(args) { console.log("fn2",args); /* do something */ }

xxx = new MyObj();

xxx.selectfn(1,"ciao");
//call xxx.fn1("ciao");
```

see the console for response.